# How can I get "ManyToManyField" values in the search filters of Haystack?

Tags: django, django-models, django-haystack

I'm implementing a filtering functionality using haystack with elasticsearch. Now, I'm getting most of all the fields to filter however I can't get the `ManyToManyField` values. In the browser is appearing like the physical address not the readable value:

I've got in my model the code below:

```
class StudyLevel(models.Model):
    name_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Institution(models.Model):
.
.
level_study = models.ManyToManyField(StudyLevel, null=True)
.
.
```

In the search_indexes is the following:

```
class InstitutionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    .
    .
    level_study = indexes.CharField(model_attr='level_study', faceted=True)
```

Now, in the search html template is the problem:

```
                {% if facets.fields.level_study %}
                    <div>
                    <h4>Study Level</h4>
                    <ul>
                    {% for level_study in facets.fields.level_study.all %}
                        <li><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&amp;selected_facets=location_exact:{{ level_study.0|urlencode }}">{{ level_study.0 }}</a> ({{ level_study.1 }})</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

How can I solve it to get those values?

Answer (score 3):

Add a Facet field for filtering

```
level_study = FacetMultiValueField()
```

and then fill it with the items from your Many-To-Many relation:

```
def prepare_level_study(self, obj):
    return [l.name for l in obj.level_study.all()]
```

and don't forget to add

```
.facet("level_study")
```

to your SearchQuerySet().